# How to get the sentence with quote in it?

Tags: c++, regex

I am trying to get correct sentence from the paragraph using C++ regex.

```
"You are welcome, most noble Sorceress, to the land of the Munchkins." Dorothy listened to this speech "carefully" with wonder.
```

This is the paragraph I am handling. I want to get the sentence starting with capital alphabet only and not surrounded by quotes. so the result must be only: `'Dorothy listened to this speech "carefully" with wonder.'`

But what I got is `'Munchkins." Dorothy listened to this speech "carefully" with wonder.'` Because alphabet in front of Munchkins is the capital one, I don't have any idea to progress from here. Does anyone have an idea ?

Following one is my regex code.

```
[^"][A-Z]+[-:?!.,"\s\w]*(?=[!?.])
```

Comment: Very unreasonable input string.  Munchkins." the full stop (.) should be after ". Otherwise this is not a sentence!

Comment: I think this question is not about C++, it is about regexps. And a good question, might be too specific. You could learn a lot by digging for the theory of the finite automatas. Note: regexps will work only until you do not need to deal with infinite deeply embedded structures (like most programming languages do).

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following should work for you.

`(?<=^|[".?!] )[A-Z].+?[!?.]`

Basically, match a capital letter, followed by a bunch of characters, then an `!`, `?`, or `.`. It should only match a sentence if it's the start of a line, or has a `?`, `.`, `"`, or `!` followed by a space before it.

- `(?<=^|[".?!] )` - Look behind: Ensure before a match it's the start of the line, or a `"`, `.`, `?`, or `!` followed by a space.
- `[A-Z].+?` - Match a capital letter, then all characters lazily.
- `[!?.]` - Match a sentence terminator.